# How to draw bitmaps on a textureview

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, image-processing, bitmap

So I had done some image processing using Opencv and camera2 api and converted the image to mat and mat to bitmap in my image listener. I've tried displaying it on an **imageview**, but for some reason the size of image that is displayed is skewed and occupies only half the screen in contrast to the camera preview (Displayed in a **textureview**) which is of full screen. Please let me know which approach to use for displaying the manipulated preview frame in a texture view efficiently and to preserve the original resolution.